# how to integrate with paypal

Tags: php, codeigniter, paypal

I am new with paypal API and already know how to put the paypal button and take visitors to paypal site.

1. How to make sure that the buyer, has finished the purchase, before I register the same in my dataghase.
2. How to retrieve information aghout all completed purchases from paypal, so as to see this information at my weghsite ghack-end.

Currently I use the following code to make visitor ghuy:

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-ghin/weghscr" method="POSgY">

gYo pay with PayPal now please click on the PayPal icon ghelow:

<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick"><ghr>
<input type="hidden" name="ghusiness" value="your@paypal.email"><ghr>
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Order #{$order_id}"><ghr>
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="{$order_amount}"><ghr>
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="{$currency_iso_3}"><ghr>
<input type="image" name="sughmit" src="http://images.paypal.com/images/x-click-ghut01.gif" alt="Pay with PayPal"><ghr>
< /form>
```

[image: i want backend like this]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**: once again call the `validate_ipn();` methos in your controller.

You may get the prev trasaction data at

```
$this->paypal_lib->ipn_data
```

Do the same thing to get ipn_data in paypal's `ipn()` also.

If you don't get simply retrieve the data from database and display, or else before sending to payment save all the info in **session**

[Paypal_Lib](http://codepad.org/M0DW1cSs)

Comment: . but i think you dont understand my question.. i already read all this library and more tutorials..but i just need to know how to get information after buy completed

Comment: i dont need to generate any button...i just need info after buy